# Position footer in A4 sized divs

Tags: html, css, printing, footer

I have some A4 sized divs with different amount of content. I try to place footers in each page with page numbers. Footer should be fixed on the bottom of the page.

```css
.page {
  border:1px solid;  
  width: 210mm;
  height: 297mm;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px
  
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="page">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut aliquet diam sit amet magna dapibus, a mollis nisi tempus. Etiam hendrerit nec dolor ac euismod. Aenean dignissim eget massa congue vestibulum. Duis volutpat semper dictum. Mauris ut magna ultricies, sagittis urna pretium, convallis est. Curabitur nisl turpis, vehicula vel luctus eu, laoreet ac neque. In congue in nulla vitae luctus. Proin quis felis consectetur, sodales elit vitae, laoreet quam.</p>
    <p>Cras pharetra, metus blandit dignissim mollis, libero erat ultrices augue, porttitor finibus velit lacus eu elit. Sed sit amet nulla gravida, interdum erat iaculis, congue sapien. Donec id magna eget sem tincidunt vulputate in vitae tortor. Proin malesuada ut leo et pharetra. Cras enim lacus, pellentesque quis mauris eget, fringilla venenatis risus. Proin varius dui eget rhoncus auctor. Praesent non egestas lorem, eget placerat nunc. Maecenas aliquet orci turpis, quis elementum sem laoreet id. Praesent metus leo, laoreet sed mollis ut, feugiat ut arcu. Vestibulum tempus elit eu neque maximus, eu vulputate leo ullamcorper. Nam commodo sem risus, vitae viverra felis lobortis a. Nulla ac leo nisl. Sed nec lobortis lacus.</p>
    <div class="footer">FOOTER page 1/2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="page"><p>Praesent non justo vitae neque viverra malesuada. Mauris sagittis venenatis diam, sed aliquet nisl sollicitudin id. Suspendisse potenti. Nullam et ornare orci. Nunc eleifend pulvinar leo, vitae viverra lorem. Nunc hendrerit pellentesque consectetur. Vivamus lectus urna, iaculis vel lectus eu, tempus laoreet quam. Integer commodo tincidunt nunc vitae hendrerit. Mauris eget ex ipsum. Mauris pellentesque iaculis metus, vel convallis tellus rutrum sit amet. Pellentesque pretium faucibus justo ut hendrerit. Phasellus vehicula blandit efficitur.</p>
    <div class="footer">FOOTER page 2/2</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/wusadisiwa/edit?html,css,output) too, to play with.

Comment: Did you try setting `position: relative` on `.page`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using `position: absolute` you have to correctly identify [containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block):

> If the position property is **absolute**, the containing block is formed by the edge of the padding box of the **nearest ancestor** element that has a **position value other than static** (fixed, absolute, relative, or sticky) (from MDN).

In your case there's no containing block with position value other than static - so `.footer` elements position themselves relative to root `html` element.

Set `position: relative` on `.page` and everything will work:

```css
.page {
  border:1px solid;  
  width: 210mm;
  height: 297mm;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="page">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut aliquet diam sit amet magna dapibus, a mollis nisi tempus. Etiam hendrerit nec dolor ac euismod. Aenean dignissim eget massa congue vestibulum. Duis volutpat semper dictum. Mauris ut magna ultricies, sagittis urna pretium, convallis est. Curabitur nisl turpis, vehicula vel luctus eu, laoreet ac neque. In congue in nulla vitae luctus. Proin quis felis consectetur, sodales elit vitae, laoreet quam.</p>
    <p>Cras pharetra, metus blandit dignissim mollis, libero erat ultrices augue, porttitor finibus velit lacus eu elit. Sed sit amet nulla gravida, interdum erat iaculis, congue sapien. Donec id magna eget sem tincidunt vulputate in vitae tortor. Proin malesuada ut leo et pharetra. Cras enim lacus, pellentesque quis mauris eget, fringilla venenatis risus. Proin varius dui eget rhoncus auctor. Praesent non egestas lorem, eget placerat nunc. Maecenas aliquet orci turpis, quis elementum sem laoreet id. Praesent metus leo, laoreet sed mollis ut, feugiat ut arcu. Vestibulum tempus elit eu neque maximus, eu vulputate leo ullamcorper. Nam commodo sem risus, vitae viverra felis lobortis a. Nulla ac leo nisl. Sed nec lobortis lacus.</p>
    <div class="footer">FOOTER page 1/2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="page"><p>Praesent non justo vitae neque viverra malesuada. Mauris sagittis venenatis diam, sed aliquet nisl sollicitudin id. Suspendisse potenti. Nullam et ornare orci. Nunc eleifend pulvinar leo, vitae viverra lorem. Nunc hendrerit pellentesque consectetur. Vivamus lectus urna, iaculis vel lectus eu, tempus laoreet quam. Integer commodo tincidunt nunc vitae hendrerit. Mauris eget ex ipsum. Mauris pellentesque iaculis metus, vel convallis tellus rutrum sit amet. Pellentesque pretium faucibus justo ut hendrerit. Phasellus vehicula blandit efficitur.</p>
    <div class="footer">FOOTER page 2/2</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @fen1x said, you have to set the position of parent div to `relative`. Just add this CSS rule.

```
.page{
  position: relative;
}
```